# rename file with name contains variable part

Tags: command-line, scripts, environment-variables, rename, mv

If i have file name (file_$i.txt). How I can change variable part in the name to be (file_$var.txt)

$i >> number of lines in file
$var >> content of other file

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: mv  file_$i.txt  file_$var.txt

why I can't rename this variable part in the file name as it understand mv command as move not rename ... and (file_$var.txt) as directory not new name

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add extra information, don't answer in comments. Please show us the _exact_ file name. What value does `$i` have? What value does `$var` have? What error are you getting?

Comment: Is there a directory named to the expansion of `file_$var.txt` in the current working directory? as if yes, then that explains why `mv` is moving instead of renaming the file in-place ... You can't have a regular file and a directory with the same name together in the same working directory as directories ar like every other datat/data container/node on the filesystem are actually all files on Ubuntu.